# TLAB taking huge amout of RAM

Tags: java

I have a java process running which has a consumer running for kafka. It consumes from kafka and stores in Hbase. The problem we are facing is it slowly starts to consume lot of RAM of the instance and eventually stops.

We have already given options: `-Xms6g -Xmx12g`, which keeps the heap size till 12g but as I am seeing in jmc, it is taking around 12g of Tlab memory allocation, as seen below:

[image]

This is happening even after I have removed `-XX:+UseTLAB` from the java command. Is there some way to give max TLab size or disable it, or how to debug why this is accumulated so much.

Comment: Have you run this through a profiling tool like VisualVM or JProfiler?

Comment: Why don't you want allocation in TLABs? Might be interesting to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/26358623/2471311 in case you are unfamiliar with TLABs. Could it be that your application has a memory leak? It might be interesting to look at the Allocation in New TLAB subtabs of that JMC page, and see what you are allocating and from which parts of your code.